# Why doesn't work js debug for intellij?

Tags: java, javascript, google-chrome, debugging

I am working with intellij and want to debug javascript. My debug configuration has "with javascript debugger". I put breakpoint on javascript variable, but I get error "ReferenceError: eventsArr is not defined" at javascript console.

And at ide I cann't evaluate this variable.

How can I debug javascript with intellij and js console?

Screen:

ide:

http://www.foto-me.ru/v.php?id=2c4d0de3efc7c42490645cc870dcefca

js console

http://www.foto-me.ru/v.php?id=b2dd3ceeb38e9443428898b4e192b2ec

Thanks.

Comment: use `console.log(variableName)` and the value should appear in your js console

Answer (score 0):

```
I think the refence file is missing. Add the file "_references.js" in your folder Scripts. And you have to reference all of the script files in this file.

Exemple _references.js file :

/// <autosync enabled="true" />
/// <reference path="jquery.validate.js" />
/// <reference path="respond.matchmedia.addlistener.js" />
/// <reference path="respond.js" />
/// <reference path="modernizr-2.7.1.js" />
/// <reference path="jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js" />
/// <reference path="jquery-2.1.0.js" />
/// <reference path="bootstrap.js" />
```